# Have a error in zend session Zend_Session_Exception

Tags: php, zend-framework

here is my code:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Session_Exception' with message 'Session must be started before any output has been sent to the browser; output started in /home/wildnet_project/MINT02_01/application/Bootstrap.php/20' in /home/wildnet_project/MINT02_01/library/Zend/Session.php:451 Stack trace: #0 /home/wildnet_project/MINT02_01/application/Bootstrap.php(145): Zend_Session::start() #1 /home/wildnet_project/MINT02_01/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(669): Bootstrap->_initDB() #2 /home/wildnet_project/MINT02_01/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(622): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('db') #3 /home/wildnet_project/MINT02_01/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(586): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap(NULL) #4 /home/wildnet_project/MINT02_01/library/Zend/Application.php(355): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap(NULL) #5 /home/wildnet_project/MINT02_01/index.php(52): Zend_Application->b in /home/wildnet_project/MINT02_01/library/Zend/Session.php on line 451

Comment: hi any one plz help me

Comment: in bootstrap i am using

Comment: Zend_Session::start();
  global $objSession;
  $objSession = new Zend_Session_Namespace('default');